# PostgreSQL update join vs SQL Server update join

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, join, update

I recently started converting a personal project from Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL and I was surprised at the abysmal performance I encountered doing an `UPDATE JOIN` between two tables.

Suppose they look something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  bar INTEGER NULL
);

CREATE TABLE foo2 (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  bar INTEGER NULL
);
```

In T-SQL I would do an update using a join using something like this:

```sql
UPDATE foo
SET bar = t2.bar
FROM foo t1
JOIN foo2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

But running in Postgres, the query is glacially slow.

If I change it to:

```sql
UPDATE foo
SET bar = t2.bar
FROM foo2 t2
WHERE foo.id = t2.id;
```

it's not a problem.

I get that the syntax is different but I would've expected the query optimizer to work out something in the same ball park. Instead, things go bananas. Besides the syntactical differences, is there a nuanced difference between the two queries that I fail to see?

#### Explain plans

```
Update on foo  (cost=85852.43..6211995294.24 rows=338326628280 width=1027)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=85852.43..6211995294.24 rows=338326628280 width=1027)
        ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..145721.10 rows=582410 width=1010)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=85852.43..247935.91 rows=580908 width=17)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=85852.43..241627.37 rows=580908 width=17)
                    Hash Cond: (t1.id = t2.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on foo t1  (cost=0.00..145721.10 rows=582410 width=10)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=75754.08..75754.08 rows=580908 width=15)
                          ->  Seq Scan on foo2 t2  (cost=0.00..75754.08 rows=580908 width=15)
```

```
Update on foo (cost=87575.47..535974.25 rows=581621 width=1022)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=87575.47..535974.25 rows=581621 width=1022)
        Hash Cond: (foo.id = t2.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on foo (cost=0.00..151301.17 rows=1140417 width=1011)
        ->  Hash  (cost=75761.21..75761.21 rows=581621 width=36)
              ->  Seq Scan on foo2 t2  (cost=0.00..75761.21 rows=581621 width=36)
```

Comment: Does the "glacially slow" query ever finish?

Comment: @fraxinus, it was running at 90 minutes at which point I cancelled it and used the `FROM WHERE` which took 30 seconds. Tbf I was also originally joining on an a non-indexed column and that query plan was `2x` the query plan in my question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> But running in Postgres, the query is glacially slow.

```
UPDATE foo
SET    bar = t2.bar
FROM   foo t1
JOIN   foo2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

There is no join condition between `foo` and `t1`, the implicit `CROSS JOIN` forces a Cartesian product, i.e. `O(N²)` (!) update operations instead of just `O(N)`. And the result is non-deterministic nonsense. The effect also becomes apparent in the query plan: `rows=338326628280` instead of `rows=581621` (Also: both plans were produced off slightly different tables, but that seems irrelevant to the question.)

*Could* be fixed by adding a join condition like:

```
UPDATE foo
SET    bar = t2.bar
FROM   foo t1
JOIN   foo2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE  foo.id = t1.id;  -- !
```

Well, technically, a `WHERE` condition, but all the same.

But that's just putting lipstick on a pig. While `id` is the PK column of each table, that's just adding noise. Use the command you already found instead:

```
UPDATE foo
SET    bar = t2.bar
FROM   foo2 t2
WHERE  foo.id = t2.id;
```

[The manual advises for the `FROM` clause of `UPDATE`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

> Do not repeat the target table as a `from_item` unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the `from_item`).

And:

> When a `FROM` clause is present, what essentially happens is that the
> target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the `from_item` list,
> and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the
> target table. When using `FROM` you should ensure that the join
> produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other
> words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other
> table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to
> update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

Such a self-join makes sense (or is even necessary!) if you need a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to additional table(s). Sadly, there is no provision in SQL to say *`"FROM LEFT"`* in an `UPDATE`. Example:

- [Nullify column in update if subquery returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22607620/939860)

Comment: In SQL Server, if `FROM` contains `foo` and `UPDATE` references `foo`, both are references to the same instance. For that reason, if you wanted to be absolutely unambiguous, you could also reference your target table in the `UPDATE` clause by its alias in the `FROM`, so you could do `UPDATE t1 SET ... FROM foo AS t1 INNER JOIN ...`. I actually thought PostgreSQL supported that as well but apparently I was mistaken.

Comment: @AndriyM: you can define an alias for the target table in the UPDATE part `update foo as t1 set ... from foo2 as t2 where ...`

Comment: just for clarification: it is not valid syntax in SQL Server but it is valid in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, I think I knew about that syntax in Postgres. I like the compactness of `UPDATE... FROM... WHERE <joining condition>`, but I still find that syntax inferior to SQL Server's explicit join option for two reasons: 1) because, while I'm not exactly condemning the joining method using `WHERE`, it's just that I *prefer* to use `JOIN... ON...`; and 2) because you can't have an outer join that way, as Erwin has already mentioned. On the other hand, it's nice that Postgres, unlike SQL Server, allows you to assign an alias in the `UPDATE` clause, certainly a convenient thing.

Comment: Can I double-check  my interpretation of your answer? Basically, it’s an `UPDATE … SET … WHERE –`, where the `WHERE` clause filters what is updated. The `FROM` clause provides the values, but doesn’t filter the `UPDATE`. IS that right?

Comment: @Manngo: `FROM` does basically the same as `CROSS JOIN` in the `FROM` clause of a `SELECT`. (But the only target table is the one in the `UPDATE` clause.) Typically, you'll want to add a `WHERE` clause to link both sides.  The `FROM` clause does *not* have to "provide the values", it might as well be used for filtering. All columns in all joined tables can provide values for the update. If anything is still unclear, start a new question, comments are not the place.

Answer (score 3):

I want to address part of the question from a SQL Server perspective.

> In T-SQL I would do an update using a join using something like this:
>
> ```
> UPDATE foo
> SET bar = t2.bar
> FROM foo t1
> JOIN foo2 t2
> ON t1.id = t2.id;
> ```

Maybe *something* like that, but probably not exactly that. It is too easy to end up with an [accidental cross join](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240864). The [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) doesn't really talk about that, but it *should* because this trips people up all the time.

Algebrization of `UPDATE...FROM` can be quirky (often for backward-compatibility), so it is important to be explicit and follow best practice. This means:

1. Assigning an alias
2. *Updating that alias*; and
3. Ensuring the update is *deterministic* i.e. each target row is updated from at most one source row.

Extracts from the same documentation page:

> If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM clause, an object alias may or may not be specified. If the object being updated appears more than one time in the FROM clause, one, and only one, reference to the object must not specify a table alias. All other references to the object in the FROM clause must include an object alias.

> Use caution when specifying the FROM clause to provide the criteria for the update operation. The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is not deterministic.

and, revealing some of the algebrization issues:

> When a common table expression (CTE) is the target of an UPDATE statement, all references to the CTE in the statement must match. For example, if the CTE is assigned an alias in the FROM clause, the alias must be used for all other references to the CTE. Unambiguous CTE references are required because a CTE does not have an object ID, which SQL Server uses to recognize the implicit relationship between an object and its alias. Without this relationship, the query plan may produce unexpected join behavior and unintended query results.

---

So the T-SQL example would be:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  bar INTEGER NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.foo2 (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  bar INTEGER NULL
);

-- Update the alias
UPDATE F1
SET F1.bar = F2.bar
FROM dbo.foo AS F1
JOIN dbo.foo2 AS F2
    ON F2.id = F1.id -- deterministic;
```

One way to check an update is deterministic in SQL Server is to first write it as a `MERGE`, which does check for non-deterministic updates at runtime. You would not routinely write a simple update as a merge for performance reasons (and maybe because merge has a few issues of its own).